# How to calculate integral $\mathbb E[\log X]$?

Tags: integration, random-variables, logarithms, expected-value

I'm trying to calculate $\mathbb E[\log X]$ for X a non-negative random variable with finite mean, and

$$\mathbb E[\log X|X\leq t]=\frac{1}{F(t)}\int_0^t \log xf(x)dx=\frac{1}{F(t)}([\log zF(z)]^t_0-\int^t_0\frac{1}{z}F(z)dz)$$ But now I don't know how to solve $[\log zF(z)]_{t=0}$ I believe this should be $0$ but have no ideal how to show it. Since $F$ is unknown L'Hôpital also doesn't work. Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't think you can obtain a generalized formula that holds for all random variables. Do you have a particular distribution in mind? Or if you are interested in an upper bound, you can directly use Jensen's inequality to conclude $\mathbb{E}[\log X] \leq \log( \mathbb{E}[X])$.

Comment: @sudeep5221 Actually I'm trying to make a simplification of $E[\log X]$ in a paper clearer. It states that $\frac{1}{F(t)}\int_0^t\log zf(z)dz=-\frac{1}{F(t)}\int_0^t\frac{F(z)}{z}dz+\log t$. I'm sorry I forgot the assumption $E[\log X]<\infty$, but I think it follows from $EX<\infty$ since jensens inequality and log is concave?

Comment: The RHS follows by application of integration by parts on the LHS.

Comment: @sudeep5221 Thanks a lot, but using integration by parts on the LHS I get $\frac{1}{F(t)}([\log z F(z)]_0^t-\int_0^t\frac{F(z)}{z}dz)$ and if  $[\log z F(z)]_0=0$ the result follows. But I don't know how to show it.

Comment: Since $X$ is non-negative, $F(x) = 0$ for all $x \leq 0$. There is a slight catch there as to how fast $F(x)$ goes to $0$ as $x \to 0$. As long as $F(x) \sim x^s$ around $x = 0$ for any $s > 0$, you should be fine.